# Obtain DLL version in C++

Tags: c++, version

Can someone point me to a function to simply grab the version number off of a DLL file using C++ code? I know Windows has the info because I can right click on the file, view the properties, and see the version. I just need to retrieve the version programmatically in C++.

Comment: You are supposed to show us what _you_ have come up with!!

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [GetFileVersionInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647003.aspx) WinAPI function. Below is a slightly modified working [example](https://vcpptips.wordpress.com/tag/getfileversioninfo/) of its use. It will print version as it is on details page. All you need is to include headers for vector and windows.h, and include version.lib, by using ie. pragma : `#pragma comment(lib, "version.lib")`

```
LPTSTR lpszFilePath = L"d:\\AcroRd32.dll";

DWORD dwDummy;
DWORD dwFVISize = GetFileVersionInfoSize(lpszFilePath, &dwDummy);

std::vector<BYTE> versionInfoVec(dwFVISize);

GetFileVersionInfo(lpszFilePath, 0, dwFVISize, versionInfoVec.data());

UINT uLen;
VS_FIXEDFILEINFO *lpFfi;

VerQueryValue(versionInfoVec.data(), _T("\\"), (LPVOID *)&lpFfi, &uLen);

DWORD dwFileVersionMS = lpFfi->dwFileVersionMS;
DWORD dwFileVersionLS = lpFfi->dwFileVersionLS;

DWORD dwLeftMost = HIWORD(dwFileVersionMS);
DWORD dwSecondLeft = LOWORD(dwFileVersionMS);
DWORD dwSecondRight = HIWORD(dwFileVersionLS);
DWORD dwRightMost = LOWORD(dwFileVersionLS);

std::cout << dwLeftMost << "." << dwSecondLeft << "."
    << dwSecondRight << "." << dwRightMost << std::endl;
```

Comment: Thank you. That was extremely helpful and provided me with the information I needed. Unfortunately I dont

Comment: have enough reputation to up vote your answer, but nevertheless i thank you for it

Comment: Don't forget to do error checking on each API call.  Also, some DLLs export a [`DllGetVersion()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776404.aspx) function, so you might consider checking for that before resorting to `GetFileVersionInfo()`.